# Android reverse engineer string resources from integer values

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, android-resources, r.java-file

I'm trying to decide on the security layer(s) I should implement to increase the protection of specific parts of my android application. In order to decide, I'm decompiling my own application to see how easily someone else can access specific parts of the code after obfuscating it with the ProGuard tool. After decompiling, the references to R.string resources become an integer value.

I would like to know, if someone can easily associate the integer values with the actual string values or if a lot of effort is required to achieve this. I'm only asking in order to see if a third party can reveal this information in no time or if it is a task that requires effort that may put off someone into getting into the trouble of mapping the values.

Thank you,
L.

Comment: Question out of curiosity, are you using ProGuard?

Comment: @Grigor: Yes, I forgot to mention it.. any feedback on my issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close since we have no way of knowing that your intentions are good.  There are other places on the web where people do not care as much as we do about protecting peoples rights.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reverse engineering software, not about creating it.

Comment: @Simon: Simon I can see your point, although I cannot prove my good intentions, my objective is just to protect my code. Please let me mention that in stackoverflow are tens of questions regarding reverse engineering aspects in android that are discussed without any problem. So, I believe that it is unfair to treat my question as  malicious. Nonetheless, your opinion is respected.

Comment: I have edited my question, requesting more generic feedback (i.e. easily done, have to spend a lot of effort, etc) in order to decide on how to proceed with protecting my application. I hope that the context of the question is now more relevant to the stackoverflow

Comment: @Simon - no, you are mistaken.  This question is about the internal structure of an android application package, hence it is very much on topic here.